# cvBlob/Opencv: Why is my output variable empty?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

When doing:

```
IplImage blobimg = image;

IplImage *labelImg=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&blobimg), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL, 1);
IplImage *test=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&blobimg), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
unsigned int result=cvLabel(&blobimg, labelImg, blobs);

cvRenderBlobs(labelImg, blobs, &blobimg,test,CV_BLOB_RENDER_BOUNDING_BOX);
Mat imgMat(test);

imshow("Depth", imgMat);
```

I notice that my test variable is empty :
[image]

I think I have to do this instead:

```
cvRenderBlobs(labelImg, blobs, &blobimg,&blobimg,CV_BLOB_RENDER_BOUNDING_BOX);
```

But cvRenderBlobs destImg has to have 3 channels and IPL_DEPTH_8U and my image has only 1 channel since it's a gray image.

Can someone tell me why this is and how I can fix this ?

**Edit**

Where image comes from:

```
Mat *depthImage = new Mat(480, 640, CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0));
Mat image = *depthImage;
```

Comment: I'm not using cvBlobsLib but cvBlobs. They are not the same :).

Comment: Sorry - yes, I realised my mistake and deleted the comment

Answer (score 0):

Will guess here but not too many times I've seen instances of IplImages that are not actually pointers. Are you sure that *image*, wherever it's coming from, isn't also a pointer to an IplImage struct?

```
    IplImage *blobimg = image;
```

Comment: i've added where it comes from to the question

Answer (score 0):

I use this portion of code in my project and it works, see if it can help:

```
//BYTE* blobMap = ... blobMap holds an image
CvMat mat = cvMat( HEIGHT, WIDTH, CV_8UC1, blobMap);
IplImage *img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(HEIGHT,WIDTH), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvGetImage(&mat, img);
cvThreshold(img, img, 10, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
IplImage *labelImg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_LABEL,1);
CvBlobs blobs;
unsigned int result = cvLabel(img, labelImg, blobs);
cvFilterByArea(blobs, 1000, 1680*HEIGHT);

IplImage *imgOut = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvRenderBlobs(labelImg, blobs, img, imgOut);
cvNamedWindow("test", 1);
cvShowImage("test", imgOut);
cvWaitKey(0);
cvDestroyWindow("test");
```

I also don't like the way you pass the Mat to an IplImage, are you sure that your input image (blobimg) is ok?

Comment: it looks like it, when i pass my Mat to an IplImage i see that the blobimg has a width , height, nChannels etc